# Aligning two divs vertically to each other in CSS

Tags: html, css

I am trying to to align one div below another and apply a margin top to the one below:

```
<div id="divContainer">
    <div id="div1">
    </div>
    <div id="div2">
        <ul>
            <li>Item 1</li>
            <li>Item 2</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

I applied a margin to the second div, but it is not working:

```
#divContainer {
    pointer-events: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    left: 10px;
}

#div1 {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

#div2 {
    padding: 10px;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border-radius: 5px;
    top: 10px;
    width: 200px;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}
```

This results in the bottom div appearing below the first one. However the `top: 10px;` has no effect. I found online that to fix the margin problem, I should use `display: inline-block;` This however causes the two divs to appear next to each other rather than one being above the other.

How do I get the desired effect while keeping the second div below the first one?

Comment: give a position to the div before applying the top,left,right or bottom attributes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to set `position: relative` on `#div2`:

```css
#divContainer {
    pointer-events: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    left: 10px;
}

#div1 {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

#div2 {
    padding: 10px;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border-radius: 5px;
    top: 10px;
    width: 200px;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    position: relative;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`top: 10px;` works only for absolutely positioned elements. `margin-top: 10px;` will work after you set `div2` position to relative.

Answer (score 0):

You're not using margin-top but using top. And to the top,right,bottom, or left values need to be positioned. By default, position is static. So, those value for static position will not work:

```
position: relative;/*or absolute, or fixed*/
top: 30px;/*give your value*/
```

Now, this works.

---

We specially use them for positioning purposes. Thus, you may just use `margin-top` instead.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you're after here, but I've created a fiddle with your code changing some colours for visibility and `top` to `margin-top` which is what I think you're after.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hv7q7fym/)